# Copy Dir with Php in Client's PC

Tags: php, copy

I tried to copy any dir  from my server to client's pc but i dont know how is possible :S...  as example... I have domain.com/Info and I want to copy that folder Info with content so I copy Info and copy in other folder but in my server...  but i don't know, how copy in client's pc, the sense of my idea is, that if any client want to use my web can to copy that folder in him desktop Any Idea?? my code for copy dir in my server is

```
function full_copy( $source, $target ) {
    if ( is_dir( $source ) ) {
        @mkdir( $target );
        $d = dir( $source );
        while ( FALSE !== ( $entry = $d->read() ) ) {
            if ( $entry == '.' || $entry == '..' ) {
                continue;
            }
            $Entry = $source . '/' . $entry; 
            if ( is_dir( $Entry ) ) {
                full_copy( $Entry, $target . '/' . $entry );
                continue;
            }
            copy( $Entry, $target . '/' . $entry );
        }

        $d->close();
    }else {
        copy( $source, $target );
    }
}
$s = '/Appserv/www/CpVela/Info';
$des = '/Info/';
full_copy($s,$des);
```

new EDIT

well I'm Trying to make and download .zip but file.zip that my code creates is empty and damaged :S

my code is this

```
include "libs/pclzip-2-8-2/pclzip.lib.php";
require("libs/zipfile.php");

/* creates a compressed zip file */
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false) {
  if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
  $valid_files = array();
  if(is_array($files)) {
    foreach($files as $file) {
      if(file_exists($file)) {
        $valid_files[] = $file;
      }
    }
  }
  if(count($valid_files)) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
      return false;
    }
    foreach($valid_files as $file) {
      $zip->addFile($file,$file);
    }
    $zip->close();
    return file_exists($destination);
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
$array = array();
function full_copy( $source, $target ) {

    if ( is_dir( $source ) ) {
        @mkdir( $target );
        //$archivo  = new zipfile();
         $archive = new PclZip('zipfile.zip');
        $d = dir( $source );
        while ( FALSE !== ( $entry = $d->read() ) ) {
            if ( $entry == '.' || $entry == '..' ) {
                continue;
            }
            $Entry = $source . '/' . $entry; 
            if ( is_dir( $Entry ) ) {
                full_copy( $Entry, $target . '/' . $entry );
                continue;
            }
            if(count($array) > 1 ){
                array_push($array, $Entry);
                }else{
                    $array[0] = $Entry;
                    }
        //  $archivo->add_file($Entry,$Entry);
             //$v_list = $archive->add($Entry, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_PATH, 'dev');
            //copy( $Entry, $target . '/' . $entry );
        }

        $d->close();


    }else {
        copy( $source, $target );
    }
}

$s = '/Appserv/www/CpVela/Info';
$des = '/Appserv/www/CpVela/';
full_copy($s,$des);
create_zip($array,'zipfile.zip');
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=zipfile.zip");
echo $zipfile->file();
```

Comment: you can't do this, php have no access to client's filesystem, only way is make tar or gzip with all needed files and give client opportunity to download it.

Comment: What a terrifying notion. Imagine if any website had the ability to make drastic changes to your file-system.

Comment: No mike no Changes only copy any folder dont make sense change in my server or a specific folder

Comment: http://ramui.com/fw_blog/upload/recurseZip.zip   - class to use, http://ramui.com/articles/php-zip-files-and-directory.html - article to read

Comment: "give error" is about the most generic description of a problem you could possibly give us...if you want more help, you'll have to be a bit more detailed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this from a web browser.  PHP runs on the server where the web page executes, and nowhere else.

If you want to allow the client to do this, you'd need to use another tool, or another language.  Or just make a zip file that he can download.

Comment: Yeah but that is the problem... I'm Trying to make and download .zip

Comment: and If i try with file.bat?? with xcopy??